# how to get pop up with two different color?

Tags: css

On this link boxover.swazz.org/ we see the box over with heading and content. I need to do the same thing but with rounded corners. Can anyone suggest me?

Thanks in advance........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.box{
  -moz-border-radius: 2em 1em;
  border-radius: 2em 1em;
}
```

Works in FF and browsers with webkit core (Safari, Konqueror).

If you need IE support, use [sliding doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/).

Comment: Thank you so much erenon. It worked for safari and FF. I still have to work for IE.